# Visual Studio Code: выполнение предварительной задачи build завершено с кодом выхода 1

Tags: c#, отладка, visual-studio-code

Доброго времени суток. 
При попытке дебажнуть свое консольное приложение написанное на c# в VS Code появляется ошибка "выполнение предварительной задачи build завершено с кодом выхода 1". [image: консольное приложение]
(При дебагге исользую ".NET Core Launch (console)" ОС: Windows 7)

VS Code советует обратится к созданным им файлам launch.jsos && task.json.

[image: launch.jsos && task.json]

Comment: Судя по тому, что у вас в launch.json есть строка `"program": ... /bin/debug/Arithmetic Progression.exe`, вы пытаетесь запустить на отладку обычное приложение под десктопный .NET. Visual Studio Code пока умеет работать только с .NET Core и mono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Решение проблемы для Windows. Подробности для других ОС на сайте ниже.*

*Проблема была в том, что я неправильно создавал проект для VS CODE и в присутствии некоторых неверных конфигураций в файле launch.json.*

Т.е. необходимые действия для работы с .net core в VS CODE:

1. Скачайте .Net Core SDK для Visual Studio Code на сайте: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core
2. Через консоль/терминал создаете проект(в необходимой для вас директории) через следующие команды:

   ```
   mkdir hwapp
   cd hwapp
   dotnet new
   ```
3. После создании папки, вам надо **в вашей папке (где будет хранится проект)** исполнить следующий код:

   ```
   dotnet restore
   dotnet run
   ```

Если вы всё сделали правильно, у вас должен получится .Net Core проект.

Далее, вам необходимо будет настроить в launch.json поле **"program"**, если по каким-то причинам VS CODE не сделал это за вас (в новых версиях есть такая проблема). Часть примера из файла launch.json отвечающая за запуск .Net Core Lounch (console)

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\VSCODE_PROSTO.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "externalConsole": false
    },
```